# Functional equations and the domain of functions.

Tags: functions

Functional equations are written as an equation consisting of the unknown function and variables. But what is the range of the variables? Like, everything that makes the expression makes sense? (well, I don't know whether this can be formally defined)

For example, the functional equation $f(1/x)=1/f(x)$, whether it means:

1. Find all functions $f$ such that for all real values $x\neq0$, $f(1/x)=1/f(x)$ or
2. Find all functions $f$ such that $f(1/x)$ and $1/f(x)$ are the same function? (this is different form 1 since it requires that 0 cannot be in the domain of $f$

Comment: A good functional equation should specify a domain and codomain, and clarify any issues such as these. Simply writing $f(1/x) = 1/f(x)$ is ambiguous, and the onus is on the person writing the question to make it clear.

Comment: well what about the range of the variable $x$ in the equation? Is there some convention for the range of it?

Comment: No, not really. To say something like $f(xy^2) = x / f(y)$, where $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ would be ambiguous. Either $0$ should be left out of the codomain, or an exception should be carved out (e.g. "unless $f(y) = 0$").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the domain of the functions should be given in the problem. If there is nothing given, you should consider that the domain of your functions should be the same. So, in your example, $0$ should not be in the domain of $f$.